Elasticsearch not sorting results when fetching all documents
Using Elasticsearch 7.17.1, if I provide a query then sorting works:
{
  "query":{
    "bool":{
      "must":[
        {
          "terms":{
            "foo":[
              "bar",
              "baz"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "min_score":0.1,
  "from":0,
  "size":300,
  "sort":{
    "pagetitle_keyword":{
      "order":"desc"
    }
  },
  "track_scores":true
}

If instead I want to return everything and use an empty query, then sorting isn't applied:
{
  "query":{
    "bool":{ }
  },
  "min_score":0.1,
  "from":0,
  "size":300,
  "sort":{
    "pagetitle_keyword":{
      "order":"desc"
    }
  },
  "track_scores":true
}

What is the cause, and how do I fix it? There are < 300 documents in this test, so the size parameter is okay.

Can you show some search results ?
